# Read JPG using Flask after being uploaded without being saved on the server

Tags: javascript, html, image, flask, http-post

I'm new to HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I'm doing a website where the user uploads an image in a drag and drop container. I want to read the uploaded JPG file using Flask once a POST request have been summited, how can I do it? For now I'm confused how the file is uploaded and how can I process it in Flask.

I'm using the method readAsDataURL, is it good practice? Since I want to display it but then I want to read the image as JPG or JPEG. Also, if I try to download it, it is saved as jfif, how does this happen?

Here's the js script where the image is uploaded:

```
dragArea.addEventListener('drop', (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent to load the page from the submit button
    file = event.dataTransfer.files[0]; // Get the file uploaded
    displayFile();
    
});

// Savve and display image after it is dropped
function displayFile() {
    let fileType = file.type;

    let validExtensions = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png'];

    if (validExtensions.includes(fileType)){
        let fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = () =>{
            let fileURL = fileReader.result;
            //console.log(fileURL);
            let imgTag = `<img src = ${fileURL}>`;
            dragArea.innerHTML = imgTag;
            dragArea.classList.add('active2');
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    else{
        alert('This file is not an image');
        dragArea.classList.remove('active');
    }
}
```

Here's the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\static\styles.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="body2">
            <div class="container">
                <h3>Upload your file</h3>
                <div class="drag-area">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="fas fa-images"></i>
                    </div>
                    <span class="header2">Drag and drop</span>
                    <span class="header2">or <span class="button">browse</span></span>
                    <input type="file" id = "opener"hidden/>
                    <span class="support">Supports: JPEG, JPG</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-container">
                <form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="input-form">
                        <input autocomplete="off" min="1" max="10" name="amount-colors" placeholder="Amount of colors" type="number">
                    </div> 
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="button-form">Upload</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>

        <script src="/static/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I was thinking something to do in the app.py script something like this:
What are the good practices? I've seen ways to do it with the library PIL, but I don't know which way suits better.

```
from flask import Flask, flash, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request, session
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('index.html')

    elif request.method == "POST":
        # Get the amount of colors
        k = request.form.get("amount-k")

        # Load up the image
        # This part will get the JPEG that the user uploaded

        # Do algorithm
        # Pass the JPG or JPEG

        # Return
        return render_template("layout.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 5000)
```

Any help or documentation is appreciated